# Are there examples in recent history of representatives moving between states in US senate?

Tags: united-states, congress

For example, are there instances of individuals being a representative for say Florida, and then in a subsequent period begin a representative for Texas?

I am guessing such situations are possible, but are there examples of this occurring? I'm specifically interested in say the last 20 years.

Comment: It would be permitted if someone changed their state of residency, but has not happened that I could find.

Comment: @MichaelBroughton - thanks - since posting question I also looked over a database of senators, and couldn't find any instances of it happening.

Comment: Well, unless you count Hillary Clinton's career as Senator for New York, and Unofficial Vice President from Arkansas ;-)

Comment: Scott Brown almost made it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From here: http://talkingpointsmemo.com/dc/scott-brown-senators-different-states

> According to the U.S. Senate Historical Office, only two senators have represented multiple states in the history of the chamber: Sen. James Shields (D) served as senator from Illinois, Minnesota and Missouri in the 19th century and Waitman Thomas Willey who represented Virginia and West Virginia roughly around the same time. Willey was a member of the Republican and Unionist parties. Shields was last elected in 1879 and Willey's last term ended in 1871.